# LibreOffice icons hard to see with dark themes

Tags: 16.04, icons, themes, libreoffice, icon-themes

I've recently installed a dark theme for Ubuntu (16.04) and it's great but the only problem I have is that I can't see the icons in LibreOffice. I've tried the default icon themes in LibreOffice but they're all the same. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: From 2017 to 2023 with same issue.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've found out that I could just install a new icon theme using the terminal. See the available themes with:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-style
```

You get this:

```
  libreoffice-style-sifr 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial3
  libreoffice-style-oxygen 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial3
  libreoffice-style-human 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial3
  libreoffice-style-hicontrast 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial3
  libreoffice-style-elementary 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial3
  libreoffice-style-tango 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial3
  libreoffice-style-galaxy 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial3
  libreoffice-style-breeze 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial3
  libreoffice-style-mint 5.1+3
```

To get the oxygen theme:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-style-oxygen
```

After a few tries I've found that oxygen icon theme works great with the dark theme I have currently installed (and will probably look good with others as well). You can select the theme from the window (Tools -> Options) in the screenshot (click to see it bigger). Here's how it looks now:

[image]

Another one that works great is `libreoffice-style-elementary`.

[image]

Sifr is not bad if you prefer monochrome.

[image]

That can be made whiter as indicated [here](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1012041/).

Comment: I know this is a simple question which has a simple answer, but it cost me a good twenty minutes or so to find this information (didn't even know libreoffice had style packages available in apt) and people were using stuff like synaptic package manager in videos etc. So, that's why I've put it here.

Comment: `E: Package 'libreoffice-style' has no installation candidate` Installing the individual style packages has no effect on my system. Libreoffice still uses the old Xorg widgets.

Comment: @Cerin before the edits to the post, it used to say "Tab completion will give the complete list if you just try to enter this command" instead (so there is no package called `libreoffice-style` it's just a list of packages you can install). You need to install an individual package and pick it from inside libreoffice, restarting libreoffice might be needed.