# LibreOffice looks in KDE like from 90's

Tags: kde, gtk, plasma, design

I have some applications (for example LibreOffice) which looks really weird, design like from 90's.

As you can see here: [image]

How can I fix it, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LibreOffice icons hard to see with dark themes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979032/libreoffice-icons-hard-to-see-with-dark-themes)

Comment: Do you have `libreoffice-kde` installed? If not, close all instances of LibreOffice, run `sudo apt-get install libreoffice-kde` and then see how LibreOffice looks.

Comment: And tell people what your desktop environment is. The tags you've used and your question's title don't give as much information as would explicitly mentioning your distro, its version, and the desktop environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your theme.

Either via gtk
https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/how-can-i-make-libreoffice-look-better

Or you install a theme directly
http://www.debugpoint.com/2016/08/quick-tip-change-the-default-libreoffice-look-and-feel/

Most application use the general theme you set. You can change the theme in the kde settings.

Comment: It doesn't work I run "sudo apt-get install libreoffice-style*" and changed theme in LibreOffice and nothing happened.

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2197774 https://askubuntu.com/questions/979032/libreoffice-icons-hard-to-see-with-dark-themes

Comment: I had to install "libreoffice-gtk"

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-kf5
```

Comment: Hi there, please provide some context as to why you think the `libreoffice-kf5` package will solve this problem. A link to some relevant documentation would be great.